# XML response in AJAX call works fine in other browsers but gives error in IE8 Windows XP

Tags: ajax, xml, internet-explorer

We return an xml file's contents on clicking a button using AJAX. It works fine in all browsers/versions. But it throws exception "Your browser does not support XML parsing" when some user tries to access it using IE 8 on Windows XP.

Comment: Please add some code also atleast for json calling and parsing of xml in client side and the conten you are getting from server as xml

Comment: It is small xml file, it is valid xml document, we have a webservice method which reads it from the database and return it to javascript code that calls this method. It works well in IE9,IE10, IE11, Google Chrome and Mozilla Fire Fox but gives error when user is using IE8 on Windows XP.

Comment: I have tested xml parsing on IE8 it's working fine can you post your ajax code and the code you are reading the xml file which triggers the error.